# Password storage (for a set of scripts)

Tags: python, perl, bash, gnupg

I have a system (actually it is a set of shell scripts) which has a lot of instances on different servers in different test stages (dev, uat, prd). Scripts need use some passwords for authorization in for example database (btw each environment has its own passwords). 
I have a deployment system, therefore I'm able to hold passwords in repository to not to update them each time manually.

But it's completely unacceptable from security point of view to store them as plain text.

I could develop a solution myself using gpg (to hold each password in gpg encrypted file with pub certificate of target environment), but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Is there any existing opensource solutions for password storage which are better than own solution with gpg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for `Password store`. You can have a look into [vault 0.2](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/vault)

Comment: +1, sounds like a good tool for the job. (Although depending on the usage, it might be simpler just to go straight to [the library it's based on](https://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib/).)

Answer (score 2):

PyCrypto.Blowfish should be very nice for that purpose:

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.Blowfish.BlowfishCipher-class.html

Although you'd have to specify key manually on each startup of your "password server" obviously.

Answer (score 1):

[PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) is a well known and mature library for this kind of thing, and should do what you are looking for.